# How to make validation stepper when form inside bottomsheet?

Tags: android, flutter, stepper

This app make a stepper. In stepper I build add data and show bottomsheet. In bottomsheet we can add data from there, but in this case how to validate stepper when we click next steps read method bottomsheet (if user not filling field showing error in stepper).

This is the method `bottomsheet`:

```
class StepperclassState extends State<Stepperclass> {

    void inputRekomen(){
      final Formlist formProvider = Provider.of<Formlist>(context, listen: false);
      showModalBottomSheet(
    //isScrollControlled: true,
    context: context,
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,

    shape : RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius : BorderRadius.vertical( top: Radius.circular(30),)

    ),
    builder: (context) => DraggableScrollableSheet(

      expand: false,
      builder: (context, scrollController) => SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: scrollController,
        child: StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter stateSetter) {
              return Container(

                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                    top: Radius.circular(30),
                  ),
                  color: Color(0xffFFFFF),
                ),
                child: Stack(
                  children: [

                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                            top: Radius.circular(30),
                          ),
                          color: white),

                      child: Stack(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 145),
                            child: Container(
                              width: 80, height: 3,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                                    top: Radius.circular(30),
                                  ),
                                  color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, right: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10),
                            child: Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Color(0xffDCE9F3),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),),
                              child: Form(
                                key: formKey3,
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [

                                    SizedBox(height: 20,),
                                    Container(
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Apa tindakan rekomendasi untuk mencegah kejadian berulang ?', style: blackregstyle.copyWith(
                                          fontSize: 14,
                                        ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(height: 30,),
                                    Container(
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Rekomendasi', style: blackregstyle.copyWith(
                                          fontSize: 14,
                                        ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 20.0, left: 20, right: 20),
                                      child: Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: Color(0xffffffff),
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                        ),
                                        child: FormBuilderTextField(

                                          validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose([
                                            FormBuilderValidators.required(context, errorText: FormBuilderLocalizations.of(context).requiredErrorText),
                                            FormBuilderValidators.minLength(context, 3, errorText: FormBuilderLocalizations.of(context).minLengthErrorText(3)),
                                            FormBuilderValidators.email(context, errorText: FormBuilderLocalizations.of(context).emailErrorText ),
                                          ]),

                                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                          decoration: InputDecoration(

                                            fillColor: Color(0xfffaebeb),
                                            filled: inputteks,
                                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                            border: InputBorder.none,
                                            focusedBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                              borderSide:  BorderSide(color: Color(0xff3F8AE0) ),

                                            ),
                                            focusedErrorBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                              borderSide:  BorderSide(color: Color(0xff3F8AE0), width: 1),
                                            ),
                                            enabledBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                              borderSide:  BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1),
                                            ),
                                            errorBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                              borderSide:  BorderSide(color: Color(0xffE64646) ),

                                            ),
                                            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,),

                                          autofocus: false,
                                          controller: rekomen,
                                          onChanged: (String value) {
                                            formProvider.tanggaltext(value);
                                            rekomen.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: rekomen.text.length));
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Penjelasan', style: blackregstyle.copyWith(
                                          fontSize: 14,
                                        ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 20.0, left: 20, right: 20),
                                      child: Container(
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: Color(0xffffffff),
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                        ),
                                        child: FormBuilderTextField(

                                          validator: FormBuilderValidators.compose([
                                            FormBuilderValidators.required(context, errorText: FormBuilderLocalizations.of(context).requiredErrorText),
                                            FormBuilderValidators.minLength(context, 3, errorText: FormBuilderLocalizations.of(context).minLengthErrorText(3)),
                                            FormBuilderValidators.email(context, errorText: FormBuilderLocalizations.of(context).emailErrorText ),
                                          ]),

                                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                          decoration: InputDecoration(

                                            fillColor: Color(0xfffaebeb),
                                            filled: inputteks,
                                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                            border: InputBorder.none,
                                            focusedBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                              borderSide:  BorderSide(color: Color(0xff3F8AE0) ),

                                            ),
                                            focusedErrorBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                              borderSide:  BorderSide(color: Color(0xff3F8AE0), width: 1),
                                            ),
                                            enabledBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                              borderSide:  BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1),
                                            ),
                                            errorBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                              borderSide:  BorderSide(color: Color(0xffE64646) ),

                                            ),
                                            disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,),

                                          autofocus: false,
                                          controller: penjelasan,
                                          onChanged: (String value) {
                                            formProvider.tanggaltext(value);
                                            penjelasan.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: penjelasan.text.length));
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Penanggung Jawab Tindakan Rekomendasi:', style: blackregstyle.copyWith(
                                          fontSize: 14,
                                        ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(height: 5,),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),

                                      child: Container(

                                        width: 280,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: Color(0xffffffff),
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                                        ),
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 5),
                                        ),

                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Column(
                                      children: [
                                        SizedBox(height: 5,),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, right: 25, left: 25),
                                          child: Container(
                                            width: 315,
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                                            ),
                                            constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                              minHeight: 45,
                                              minWidth: 315,
                                            ),
                                            child: Row(
                                              children: [
                                                Expanded(
                                                  child: Padding(
                                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
                                                      child: GestureDetector(
                                                        onTap: () {
                                                          stateSetter(() {
                                                            showdropdown = showdropdown == true ? false : true;
                                                          });
                                                          print(showdropdown);
                                                          print(chosenValue1);
                                                        },
                                                        child: chosenValue == -1 ?  Text(
                                                            'Penanggung Jawab'
                                                        ) : Text(
                                                            '${penanggung[chosenValue]}'
                                                        ),
                                                      )

                                                  ),),
                                                GestureDetector(
                                                  onTap: () {
                                                    stateSetter(() {
                                                      showdropdown = showdropdown == true ? false : true;
                                                    });
                                                    print(showdropdown);
                                                    print(chosenValue1);
                                                  },
                                                  child: Icon
                                                    (
                                                    showdropdown ?
                                                    Icons.arrow_drop_up_rounded : Icons.arrow_drop_down_rounded,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),

                                        Visibility(
                                          visible: showdropdown,
                                          child: Stack(
                                            children: [
                                              Container(
                                                height: 100,
                                                width: 290,
                                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                ),
                                                child: Padding(
                                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                                                  child: ListView.builder(
                                                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                                    itemCount: penanggung.length,
                                                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {

                                                      return InkWell(
                                                        onTap: () {
                                                          stateSetter(() {
                                                            chosenValue = position;

                                                            if ( position == 2){
                                                              showTextField1 = true;
                                                              showdropdown = false;
                                                              buttonshow = false;
                                                            }
                                                            else{
                                                              showTextField1 = false;
                                                              showdropdown = false;
                                                              buttonshow = true;
                                                            }
                                                          });
                                                        },
                                                        child: Container(
                                                          width: 150,
                                                          child: Container(
                                                            decoration: (chosenValue==position)
                                                                ? BoxDecoration(
                                                                border: Border.all(color: Colors.green))
                                                                : null,
                                                            child: Column(
                                                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                                              children: <Widget>[
                                                                SizedBox(height: 5,),
                                                                Text(penanggung[position], textAlign: TextAlign.left, ),
                                                                SizedBox(height: 5,),
                                                              ],
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      );
                                                    },
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),

                                    Visibility(
                                      visible: buttonshow,
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 24),
                                        child: Container(
                                          height: 44,
                                          child: RaisedButton(
                                            onPressed: loading ? null : (){ stateSetter(() {
                                              loading = true;
                                              validateAndSave();
                                              formProvider.submit();
                                            });  },
                                            color: Color(0xff4986CC),
                                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(17),
                                            ),
                                            child: Text(
                                              'Simpan', style: putihstyle.copyWith(
                                              fontSize: 14,
                                            ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Center(
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: [
                                          Opacity(opacity: loading ? 1.0 : 0,
                                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),)
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Visibility(
                                      visible: showTextField1,
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          
                                          Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, left: 24),
                                            child: Container(
                                              height: 40,
                                              child: RaisedButton(
                                                onPressed: loading ? null : (){ stateSetter(() {
                                                  loading = true;

                                                  validateAndSave();
                                                  formProvider.submit();
                                                });  },
                                                color: Color(0xff4986CC),
                                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(17),
                                                ),
                                                child: Text(
                                                  'Simpan', style: putihstyle.copyWith(
                                                  fontSize: 14,
                                                ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),

                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ), ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
}
```

this is my stepper

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    CoolStep(
        
        title: 'Identitas',
        subtitle: 'Isi Identitas Saksi/korban',
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        content: Stack(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
              child: Container(
                width: 461,
                height: 350,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xffDCE9F3),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(23),),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all( 20),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: 221,
                        height: 146,
                        
                      ),
                      
                      
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

              ),
            ),
            Stack(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 320, left: 250),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [

                      FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () => setState(() {
                        inputRekomen();
                      }),
                        tooltip: 'Tambahkan',
                        child: Icon(Icons.add,),
                        backgroundColor: Color(0xff5D99C5),

                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),

          ], ),
        validation: () {
          return null;
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this can help solve the problem, since the problem is not clear enough.
First, you need to wrap all if the steps form in Form, Set the key from the class property. for example:

```
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

then on build method, on the Form widget set the key:

```
child: Form(
    key: _formKey,
    ...
```

and then on each TextFormField, put validator on it for example:

```
validator: (value) {
    if (value!.isEmpty) {
        return 'Name is required';
    }
    return null;
}
```

then, when you need validation/checking on another methods in bottomsheet just call these function:

```
if (!_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
    return 'Fill form correctly';
}
```

Comment: still not work, because i build form in statefulbuilder, but my stepper in statfulwidget its deferent

Comment: and this stepp is function not widget, so cannot wrap form

Comment: can you share the  stepp is function that you mention also?

Comment: in the question already, CooolStep() is the list of step[]

Comment: that is the widget,,, :D